# Не могу собрать запрос MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 3 таблицы: Countries, Brands, Cars. Вот фиддл, с готовыми таблицами: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/34629/63

Задача: Вывести список самых дешевых автомобилей каждой марки (название авто + название марки)

Попытка решения:

```
select top 1 Cars.Name, Brands.Name, min(Price) from Cars
join Brands on Cars.BrandID = Brands.ID
group by Cars.Name
ORDER BY min(Price)
```

Подскажите, в каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MS SQL есть такая штука TOP 1 WITH TIES. Вот как это будет выглядеть:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
  Cars.Name, Brands.Name, Cars.Price
FROM Cars
  INNER JOIN Brands ON Cars.BrandID = Brands.ID
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Cars.BrandID ORDER BY Cars.Price )
```

Второй способ, дающий аналогичный результат:

```
SELECT 
  SQ.CarsName, SQ.BrandsName, SQ.Price 
FROM
(
  SELECT RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Cars.BrandID ORDER BY Cars.Price ) 
AS RankRow,
    Cars.Name AS CarsName, Brands.Name AS BrandsName, Cars.Price AS 
Price
  FROM Cars
    INNER JOIN Brands ON Cars.BrandID = Brands.ID
) SQ
WHERE SQ.RankRow = 1
```

Рабочий вариант, предложенный Сергеем будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT 
  c.Name AS CarsName, 
  SQ.BrandName AS BrandName, 
  c.Price AS Price 
FROM Cars c
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    b.ID AS BrandID, b.Name AS BrandName, MIN(c.Price) AS Price
  FROM Cars c
    INNER JOIN Brands b ON c.BrandID = b.ID
  GROUP BY b.ID, b.Name
) SQ ON c.Price = SQ.Price AND c.BrandID = c.BrandID
```

В этом случае результат скорее подогнанный, потому что делать JOIN по цене как то плохо выглядит, а включить Cars.Name в GROUP BY мы не можем, получим не правильный результат.

Comment: Не работает, плюс не понятно что происходит в ордер бай, если не сложно распишите, пожалуйста

Comment: В том фиддл, который вы прислали всё работает, проверьте всё ли правильно скопировалось.  Что касается принципа работы: эта конструкция введена ещё в MS SQL Server 2008, суть её заключается в том, чтобы вывести по 1 записи отсортированой по полю Cars.Price относительно поля Brands.ID.

Comment: Я в ответ добавил ещё одну конструкцию, которая работает аналогично, но более понятна к объяснению. Там суть в следующем: нумеруем цены на тачки относительно каждого бренда - это делает RANK() далее в запросе верхнего уровня оставляем только с номером 1 - самые дешёвые.

Comment: А `group by Cars.Name` вообще не работает в sql-server?

Comment: Почему же? Всё работает. Просто конкретный запрос ни в одном SQL сервере работать не будет, потому что в конце нужно написать group by Cars.Name, Brands.Name, иначе будет ошибка. Сейчас допишу в ответ Ваш вариант, Сергей, а то у меня репутации маловато, чтобы комментить чужие комментарии =)

Comment: Андрей, спасибо. Я посмотрел другие ваши ответы, они у вас полезные, не понимаю, почему их не плюсовали. Но теперь справедливость восстановлена:-), и вы комментировать сможете. А вот "мой" вариант переделанный вам бы все равно пришлось у себя размещать - код в комментариях совершенно нечитаем, да и от "моего" у вас процентов 20%:-) (я только вчера курс mySQL закончил, так что ошибаюсь пока).

Comment: Андрей, и я всё же доделал мой вариант - см. обновлённый ответ. Вполне он приличный на мой взгляд, никакой подгонки (и join ровно там, где надо, а дальше - классическое WHERE с вложенным выражением на несколько значений). Не подскажете, а почему не запустился в фиддле, что за ошибка?

Comment: Сергей, да, вы круто написали запрос и он отлично работает в MySQL. Но к сожалению в MS SQL не работает конструкция WHERE (BrandID, Price) IN.

Answer (score 2):

1. `top 1` выглядит излишним. Вы уже группируете по марке.
2. В задании выше у вас не написано про порядок вывода. `ORDER BY min(Price)` тогда излишен, при автоматической проверке может вызывать отказ.
   Да и избыточность кода это повышает, если нет условия обязательного.

Предлагаемый код (убрал прежний нерабочий код, дописал новый):

```
select Cars.Name, Brands.Name, Price 
from Cars 
join Brands on Cars.BrandID = Brands.ID
WHERE (BrandID, Price) IN
(SELECT BrandID, min(Price) 
FROM Cars
GROUP BY BrandID);
```

Я знаю mySQL, а не sql-server, не получилось запустить в фиддле, выдает ошибку (указал ниже). Но в mySQL я получил результат:

```
Query result:
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Name      | Name       | Price |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Rio       | KIA        | 734   |
| Solaris   | Hyundai    | 746   |
| Granta    | LADA       | 404   |
| Corolla   | Toyota     | 1173  |
| Outlander | Mitsubishi | 1449  |
| Qashqai   | Nissan     | 1120  |
+-----------+------------+-------+
Affected rows: 6
```

Ошибка в фиддле: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Comment: Куда-то пропали все комментарии, возможно, кто-то из великих отредактировал. Оно и к лучшему. А ответ я обновил, теперь код почти идеален:-)

Comment: код 2 раза ходит в таблицу Cars - это не хорошо, когда можно сходить 1 раз

Comment: почему? Это вложенный запрос - довольно стандартная вещь. И очень наглядная. Но да, с TOP1 - покороче. ро идеальность я, впррочем,  шучу, это к тому, что в фиддле не работает.